# Cut command to find the data between strings

Tags: bash

Can you help me in using any unix command to cut the data between files

my files:

```
MYFILES_DATA_SOMETHING_20150428.xml
MYFILES_DATA_SOMETHING_20150429.xml.gz etcc....
```

I want to find only the date between these files and store in array.
eg, i have tried like

```
echo MYFILES_DATA_SOMETHING_20150428.xml  | cut -d '_' -f4
```

but it gives me 20150428.xml  . but i want only dates in all the files.

Answer (score 4):

You have to go through another `cut` operation setting `.` as the delimiter:

```
$ echo 'MYFILES_DATA_SOMETHING_20150428.xml' | cut -d_ -f4 | cut -d. -f1
20150428
```

This can be done using many tools:

Using `bash` or any POSIX shell:

```
$ var='MYFILES_DATA_SOMETHING_20150428.xml'
$ var="${var##*_}"
$ echo "${var%.*}"
20150428
```

Using GNU `grep`:

```
$ echo 'MYFILES_DATA_SOMETHING_20150428.xml' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
20150428
```

Using GNU `sed`:

```
$ echo 'MYFILES_DATA_SOMETHING_20150428.xml' | sed 's/^.*_\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1/'
20150428
```

You can also use `expr` (thanks to Stéphane Chazelas):

```
$ var='MYFILES_DATA_SOMETHING_20150428.xml'
$ expr "x$var" : '.*_\([^.]*\)'
20150428
```

Using `python`:

```
$ python2 -c 'print "MYFILES_DATA_SOMETHING_20150428.xml".split("_")[-1].split(".")[0]'
20150428
```

Comment: @creativeindian1984 If this answer solved your problem, select it as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of the answer so that this issue can be marked as solved..

Comment: @creativeindian1984: You can mark the post as an answer. It seems to be the one and a good answer.